# MySQL Count Matching Column

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I'm having trouble with subqueries and COUNT() using multiple tables in MySQL.

For example, I have two tables:

**t1**

```
id | name
42 | John
22 | Mary
77 | Nick
```

**t2**

```
userid | merchandise | type
  22   |    Skirt    | clothes
  22   |    Scarf    | clothes
  22   |    Purse    | clothes
  77   |    Grill    | home
  22   |    Pen      | office
  42   |    Jacket   | clothes
```

I want to count the *types* in table 2 by using both tables. So for example, a desired output will be:

**Number of *clothes* purchased for each user**

```
name | count_clothes
Mary | 3
John | 1
Nick | 0
```

The best MySQL query I came up with so far is:

```
SELECT t1.name, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE type = 'clothes'
) as count_clothes
FROM users
ORDER BY count_clothes;
```

But the output it's giving me is:

```
name | count_clothes
Mary | 3
John | 3
Nick | 3
```

I know the flaw is my COUNT() query. I've tried matching the ID columns but it keeps returning an error saying *subquery is returning more than 1 row*.

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause in your subquery, so it's counting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join and `SUM()` with expression ,using sum with expression will evaluate it as boolean 1 or 0 based on expression result,so it will work as a count

```
SELECT u.id,
SUM(uc.`type`='clothes') count_clothes
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_clothes uc ON(u.id =uc.user_id)
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY count_clothes;
```

If you still want to use a subquery you need to use it like as co-related subquery,but sometimes it lacks performance so it is not recommended

```
SELECT t1.name, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE type = 'clothes' AND t1.id=user_id
) as count_clothes
FROM users t1
ORDER BY count_clothes;
```

Comment: Works great now. Can you provide me with some great resources on JOINING tables?

Comment: @user2902009 The great resource where i have learnt alot is stackoverflow :) review past answers for [*mysql tag*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) or any other database related tag, and you will learn all the expert knowledge

Comment: @user2902009 [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables rather than using a subquery.

```
SELECT t1.name, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.userid), 0) AS count_clothes
FROM users t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.userid and t2.type = 'clothes'
GROUP BY t1.name
ORDER BY count_clothes DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14deb3/4)

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` in order to get the users with zero clothes. And you have to count `t2.userid` rather than `COUNT(*)` so it doesn't count the null matches.

The problem with your subquery is that the `WHERE` clause didn't select a specific `userid`, so it just counted all users every time.

Comment: I think its not work, because its produce the result like `Nick=1` so, its `wrong one`..

Comment: Fixed it, I changed `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(t2.userid)`.

Comment: Yeah, Now Its looks fine, check this one also @user2902009, and get `(+1)` for useful `answer` and `update`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.name,
IFNULL(count(t2.userid),0) AS count_clothes
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.userid
WHERE t2.type="clothes"
GROUP BY t2.userid
```

Comment: It almost works...but is it possible to count "ZERO" for other users?